Is "Why don't you and them fight?" correct?
Is this an incorrect usage, or should it be "Why don't you and they fight?" The latter sounds awkward/wrong to my ear, but seems possibly more correct if both you and they are subjects of the verb? I'm wondering if there is some kind of mental link to the sentence "Why don't you fight them?"

He and she married. You and they are to blame. Why don't he and she get married? Why don't you and they fight?

You wouldn't say "Why don't them fight?" (at least, I hope you wouldn't).

See for example this question - and I think there are other relevant ones that I can't find.

I remember my father using a similar expression as a punchline/ ironic comment to describe someone who tried to stir up trouble for other people. Evidently, there was an older verbal challenge in his part of the U.S. (southeast Texas) that took the form "Let's you and me fight!" But in his joke version of this direct confrontation, as put in the mouth of the troublemaker, the expression became "Let's you and him fight!"
